# error while generating pascal triangle

Tags: c, pascals-triangle

This is my code to generate Pascal's triangle in C language.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int i, n, c;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c <= (n - i - 2); c++)
            printf(" ");
        for (c = 0; c <= i; c++)
            printf("%ld", factorial(i) / (factorial(c)*factorial(i - c)));
        printf("\n");
    }
    getche();
}

long factorial(int n)
{
    int c;
    long res = 1;
    for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
        res = res*c;
    return(res);
}
```

On compilation it shows **two** errors:

- conflicting types for 'factorial'
- previous implicit declaration of    'factorial' was here

What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> conflicting types for 'factorial'
>   previous implicit declaration of 'factorial' was here

Both errors refers to one thing: The function `factorial` shall be declared before used.
Simply move the definition before `main` or write a declaration for it before `main`.

I'd not write a detailed explanation for you as there're already some, e.g. [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Comment: @shri_wahal My pleasure to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `factorial` in `main` before you define it. This is legal in C, but makes the compiler guess that your function returns an `int`. However, when reaching the definition of `factorial`, the compiler notices that it returns, actually, a `long`, which causes the error.

You can fix this in two ways:

1. Swap the definitions of `main` and `factorial` or
2. Introduce a forward declaration of `factorial` before definition of `main` by adding `long factorial(int n);`.